# Handling Client Errors exceptions on GuzzleHttp

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

im trying to handdle request status code, basically checking if the status is 200, in case that it isnt handle it. Im using a package called "GuzzleHttp\Client", when there is a 404 it gives me a error:

```
Client error: `GET https://api.someurl---` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{"generated_at":"2017-09-01T16:59:25+00:00","schema":"","message":"No events scheduled for this date."}
```

But than in the screen is displayed in a format that i want to change, so im trying to catch and give a different output on the view. But is not working, it stills gives me the red screen error.

```
try {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $request = $client->request('GET', $url);
            $status = $request->getStatusCode();
            if($status == 200){
                return $status;

            }else{

                throw new \Exception('Failed');
            }

        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e) {
            //Catch errors
            return $e->getStatusCode();

        }
```

Comment: So you're trying to catch 404 exception from your guzzle request or just a connection exception?

Comment: im trying to check if 404 or other status code like 200

Answer (score 9):

Okay so if you want to stick with a try-catch you want to do something like this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

try {
    $request = $client->request('GET', $url);
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e) {
    // This is will catch all connection timeouts
    // Handle accordinly
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    // This will catch all 400 level errors.
    return $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
}

$status = $request->getStatusCode();
```

If the catch doesn't get triggered the `$request` would be successful meaning it'll have a status code of 200.
However to to catch the 400 error, ensure you've got `http_errors` request option is set to true when setting up the `$client`.